# how to make <body> in center of web page?

Tags: html, css

`margin: 0 auto` not working when the body width is set. why?

```css
body {
    width: 960px;
}
#header {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: Green;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<html>
   <head>
       <title>Menu</title>
       <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="menu.css" />
   </head>
   <body>
    <div id="header">
        
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: it's very basic question, already ask more time this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`margin: 0 auto;` works only when applied with `width` or `max-width` css property. You have set `width` on body while `margin: 0 auto` on `#header` which is wrong. Move your `width` or `max-width` to `#header` as well.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
#header {
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #0f0;
    max-width: 500px; // you can set width if you don't need responsive page
}
```

```html
<html>
   <head>
       <title>Menu</title>
       <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="menu.css" />
   </head>
   <body>
    <div id="header">
        
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

you cannot set width for body

set margin and padding for your body, and set with for your header div,

```
body 
{
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
}
#header
{
   width:960px;
   height:100px;
   background-color:Green;
   margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

`*{margin:0 auto}`

Comment: Omar, your solution is not correct, plz try it first before posting as answer